# Close dialog in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have this simple dialog in JavaFX:

```
Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create()
                .children(new Text(text), new Button("Close")).alignment(Pos.CENTER).padding(new Insets(5)).build(), xSize, ySize, backgroundColor));
dialogStage.show();
```

I want to close the dialog when I click on a `Close` button so I modified the code this way:

```
Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create()
                .children(new Text(text), new Button("Close").setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        aboutDialog();
    }
})).alignment(Pos.CENTER).padding(new Insets(5)).build(), xSize, ySize, backgroundColor));
dialogStage.show();
```

But I get this error message in Netbeans: `'void' type not allowed here`

Can you tell em what is the proper way to close the dialog using the `Close` button?

Comment: currently, when the close button is hit, a method named "aboutDialog" is called. what does it do?

Comment: It's just a small dialog window.

Comment: that was not my question, however, i simply posted a code snippet that works for what you want to do.

Comment: why not use showAndWait() instead of show()?

Comment: Just for the information you can simplify your 'onAction' declaration :
`new Button("Close").setOnAction(e -> aboutDialog())`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
  aboutDialog();
}
```

try

```
@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
  dialogStage.hide();
}
```

Comment: hmmm I'm curious As I think `close()` would free resources hold by the dialog while `hide` would just make the dialog disappear, I could be wrong anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have a `'void' type not allowed here` because when you call the `setOnAction` method it returns a `void` object. To avoid this problem you need to had the handler outside your builder like this:

```
Button but = new Button("Close");
but.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
      aboutDialog();
   }
});

Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(VBoxBuilder.create()
                .children(new Text(text), but).alignment(Pos.CENTER).padding(new Insets(5)).build(), xSize, ySize, backgroundColor));
dialogStage.show();
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you how I can place the button at the bottom of the dialog?

Comment: You should create a ``BorderPane`` instead of a ``VBox`` and add the button to the bottom with the ``setBottom`` method and add your text to the center part